# Improve fetching tasks so there are no multiple enumerations

Tags: c#, async-await, ienumerable, enumeration

I have a do while which looks like this:

```
var tasks = await _JobProvider.FetchPendingTasks();

    do
    {
      foreach (var task in tasks)
      {
        await ExecuteStep(task);
      }

      tasks = await _JobProvider.FetchPendingTasks();
    }
    while (tasks.Any());
```

I fetch the pending task and it for example returns me one task inside a `IEnumerable`. Inside `await ExecuteStep(task);` more tasks could be generated. this is why i am doing the second `tasks = await _JobProvider.FetchPendingTasks();`. With it I check if new task were generated inside `await ExecuteStep(task);` and if there are it does the `do while` loop again. This causes a mutiple enumeration of `tasks` which I think could be improved.

Is there a way to improve this code so there are no more multiple enumerations?

Comment: It sounds like you want to change how `_JobProvider` works, so that calling `ExecuteStep` won't cause more tasks to be returned from `_JobProvider.FetchPendingTasks`? But you haven't told us how `ExecuteStop` or `_JobProvider.FetchPendingTasks` work.

Comment: I tried to keep it simple, thats why i didn't explain `ExecuteStop` and `_JobProvider.FetchPendingTasks``. I explained what they are basically doing. I will update my question to more clear

Comment: If calling `ExecuteStep` can add more tasks to `_JobProvider.FetchPendingTasks`, and you want to execute those new tasks, I don't think you can avoid calling `_JobProvoider.FetchPendingTasks` again... You could simplify things a little with `await Task.WhenAll(tasks)`.

Comment: I see hmmmmm. I hoped that it is a common issue what i am having and i only have to change something small in the algorithm.

Comment: I mean, the restrictions you've placed on us are that `ExecuteStep` and `_JobProvider.FetchPendingTasks` can't change. Since that's the case, you have to work with them. If they can change, then change them to behave in a different way, which is in line with how you want to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [`Queue<Task>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1), and enumerate it endlessly with a `while` loop instead of `foreach`:

```
var queue = new Queue<Task>(await _JobProvider.FetchPendingTasks());
while (queue.Count > 0)
{
    var task = queue.Dequeue();
    Task[] moreTasks = await ExecuteStep(task);
    foreach (var t in moreTasks) queue.Enqueue(t);
}
```

This assumes the `Queue<Task>` will not be accessed concurrently by multiple threads. Otherwise you could use a [`ConcurrentQueue<Task>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1).